# Putnam And Beyond Problem 166

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

**From Putnam and Beyond :**
[Problem 166](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMZQz.png)

**Solution**

[Solution 166](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bom0R.png)

Can someone explain why the answer is the polynomials of the form $ P(x)=ax^2+a-a^2 $ and not of the form $ P(x)=ax+a-a^2 $.

Comment: You are rigth. It is a typo.

Comment: it is not a typo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for $$P(x)=ax^2+a-a^2$$ we get
$$P'(x)=2ax$$ thus $$P(P'(x))=4a^2x^2+a-a^2$$ and $$P'(P(x))=2a(ax^2+a-a^2)=2a^2x^2+2a^2-2a^3$$ this is not equal
for $$P(x)=ax+a-a^2$$ we get
$$P(P'(x))=a$$ and $$P'(P(x))=a$$ therefore $$P(x)=ax+a-a^2$$ is the right solution